# Weyl Hamiltonian - Monopole in momentum space

Tags: topology, weyl-semimetal

Consider the Weyl Hamiltonian in momentum space:
$$
\mathcal{H} = \hbar v_F \chi (\bf{\sigma}\cdot{\bf k}) ,
$$
where $\sigma^i$ are the Pauli matrices and $\chi$ the chirality of the Weyl node. Denoting the eigenstates by $|u_{n\chi}({\bf k})\rangle$, with $n = \pm$ for the conduction/valence band, we find for the Berry curvature
$$
\Omega_{n\chi}({\bf k}) = {\bf \nabla}_{\bf k}\times\langle u_{n\chi}({\bf k}) |i{\bf \nabla}_{\bf k}|u_{n\chi}({\bf k})\rangle = -\frac{n\chi\bf k}{2|{\bf k}|^3}.
$$ 
I have read in the literature on Weyl semimetals that ``a cone with chirality $\chi$ has a Berry curvature that is a monopole with charge $\chi$". However, I do not understand how the band index relates to this. If we consider the valence band, then $n = -1$, and indeed we can integrate the Berry curvature over a unit sphere, leading to
$$
\int_{\bf k}\text{d}{\bf S}\cdot\Omega_{+\chi}({\bf k}) = 2\pi \chi.
$$
Doing this for the conduction band obviously gives the opposite sign. Does this mean that the above statement only holds for the valence band? Or should I do the integral above for the upper half of the sphere with $n = +1$ and for the lower half of the sphere with $n=-1$? In that case one simply finds zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Berry curvature is a measure of how a wavefunction's phase changes as you move around in phase-space. In our typical quantum-mechanics setting, this corresponds to how an energy eigenstate changes as we vary parameters in the Hamiltonian.

Generally speaking, it is common to implicitly refer to the ground state when talking about Berry curvature. For the case of the Weyl Hamiltonian, this means you only take the valence band, ie you fix $n=-1$.